# I made a bunch of wordpress sites for clients and built off of the core theme (I didn't use a child them). What are my options now?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I didn't know about the best practice of not skinning/modifying/working off of the core wordpress theme (twenty-ten, twenty-eleven, twenty-twelve, twenty-thirteen), and a bunch of my clients sites are running right now on the core themes with a custom/modified skin.

I've heard stories of wordpress getting hacked and sites being compromised because wordpress is out of date. The wordpress team also pretty much states that security issues are being fixed with each update. I need to update the core wordpress files on these sites to prevent this, but now I'm scared that if I update wordpress, the theme will be overwritten.

In fact, I had a client click the update button once in the wordpress admin (not really knowing what they were doing) and overwrite the theme (that was pretty disasterous). I even use a plugin now to disable that message so my other clients don't do that.

What steps should I take now to fix this? Copy the theme, rename the folder/theme name in style.css, and change the theme in admin settings? Would I be OK to update wordpress after I do this? Or are there more steps that I need to take?

Comment: Yes. Copy the theme, rename the folder/theme name in style.css, and change the theme in admin settings. That should prevent overwriting the files on update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Copy the theme folder and rename the new copy to something else like `customtheme`.  Then edit `customtheme`'s theme info in the comments at the top of `style.css` and switch to it in the admin panel.  After that you are safe to update.

Do keep in mind that it's possible WP updates will break things anyway, depending on how you implement custom functionality and what plugins you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the above. Don't go anywher near the WP core or the default themes. Either create child themes or better off, build your own.

Copying and renaming and existing theme will cause you all sorts of problems as each theme uses named functions. If you just rename the stylesheet there will be more conflicts than you can fix in a week of debugging.

If you are blocking the update messages you are putting your clients at risk.